# React treating functional component as an object {Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to render an Alert component that should render when a prop has been passed to it from the parent component but I am getting an error

> Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object
> with keys {message, showAlerts}). If you meant to render a collection
> of children, use an array instead.

I'm not sure why react is treating my functional component as an object. Code sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-smoke-mij6ke?file=/src/App.js:0-3054

Here is the parent component:

```
import styled from "styled-components";
import { useTable } from "react-table";
import Alert from "react-bootstrap/Alert";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";
import axios from "axios";

import AppAlerts from "./components/Alerts";

const Styles = styled.div`
  padding: 1rem;

  table {
    border-spacing: 0;
    border: 1px solid black;

    tr {
      :last-child {
        td {
          border-bottom: 0;
        }
      }
    }

    th,
    td {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0.5rem;
      border-bottom: 1px solid black;
      border-right: 1px solid black;

      :last-child {
        border-right: 0;
      }
    }
  }
`;

function Table({ columns, data }) {
  // Use the state and functions returned from useTable to build your UI
  const {
    getTableProps,
    getTableBodyProps,
    headerGroups,
    rows,
    prepareRow
  } = useTable({
    columns,
    data
  });

  const [showAlert, setShowAlert] = useState(false);
  const [alertMessage, setAlertMessage] = useState("");
  const handleButttonClick = () => {
    setShowAlert(true);
    setAlertMessage("dummy text");
  };

  // Render the UI for table
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <AppAlerts message={alertMessage} showAlerts={showAlert} />;
      </div>

      <table {...getTableProps()}>
        <thead>
          {headerGroups.map((headerGroup) => (
            <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
              {headerGroup.headers.map((column) => (
                <th {...column.getHeaderProps()}>{column.render("Header")}</th>
              ))}
            </tr>
          ))}
        </thead>
        <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
          {rows.map((row, i) => {
            prepareRow(row);
            return (
              <tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
                {row.cells.map((cell) => {
                  return (
                    <td {...cell.getCellProps()}>{cell.render("Cell")}</td>
                  );
                })}
              </tr>
            );
          })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <Button onClick={handleButttonClick}>Open Alert box</Button>
    </div>
  );
}

function App() {
  // const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  // const [columns, setColumns] = useState([]);

  const columns = React.useMemo(
    () => [
      { Header: "Id", accessor: "id" },
      { Header: "Applicant", accessor: "applicant" },
      { Header: "Pincode", accessor: "pincode" },
      { Header: "District", accessor: "district" },
      { Header: "State", accessor: "state" }
    ],
    []
  );
  const data = React.useMemo(
    () => [
      {
        id: 18,
        applicant: "Buzz",
        pincode: 560096,
        district: 1,
        state: 1
      },
      {
        id: 19,
        applicant: "Sue",
        pincode: 560100,
        district: 2,
        state: 1
      }
    ],
    []
  );

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Styles>
        <Table columns={columns} data={data} />
      </Styles>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The child component:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Alert from "react-bootstrap/Alert";

export default function AppAlerts(message, showAlerts) {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(showAlerts);

  return (
    <Alert
      variant="info"
      onClose={() => setShow(false)}
      show={show}
      dismissible
    >
      <p>{message}</p>
    </Alert>
  );
}
```

What am i doing wrong here and what should I change?

I tried to rendering the child component for Alerts in what I think is the accepted way. On clicking the button, the Alert component must render and the alert box must open up. On dismissing the alert, the state variable for showing the alert(showAlerts) must change to 'false'  in the parent component as well.

Comment: first of all, change this: `export default function AppAlerts(message, showAlerts)` to this `export default function AppAlerts({message, showAlerts})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this:

```js
export default function AppAlerts(message, showAlerts) { ... }
```

to this:

```js
export default function AppAlerts({message, showAlerts}) { ... }
```

because props are always an object, and they get passed (always) as the first argument.

and using curly braces in the parameter list means *you're destructing the first argument (which is the props argument)*